# How to remove white space on the right side of a div because of word wrap?

Tags: html, css

When rescaling the browser window to a really small size there are always sizes that are causing the text on the right side to create some space because of the word wrap to the new line. How can I right align it with word wrap?

**What I've tried:**

```css
display: inline;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
white-space: nowrap; // not giving me the expected results as I want to keep the padding and the breaks
```

```css
.page-container {
  padding: 160px 48px 48px 48px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: calc(1080px + 96px);
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.title-container {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 60vw;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div className="page-container">
  <div className="title-container">
    <h1>
      Text <br /> More Text
    </h1>
    <br />
    <h3>Item1 / Item2 / Item3 / Item4 / Item5</h3>
    <br />
    <h2>Element1 / Element2 / Element3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bash-f98ckp?file=/src/App.js:67-359

Comment: There is no actual way to remove the white-space as it is not controllable. The only thing you could try is `text-align: justify`

Comment: `text-align: justify` Is not what I'm looking for, this would look odd with headings.

Comment: how so? the content will only be spread for every line that is not the last line. So there should be no issue with headings.

Comment: `text-align: justify;` always look odd and unreadable. So if the h2 (in you code example) breaks to 2 rows you want it to be "element 1 (left align) : element 2 (right align) : element 3 (left align)?